# Business Week logic in Oracle SQL

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle-sqldeveloper

I am using the following Oracle SQL query to work out if a week is more than 6 business weeks ago.

```
,CASE 
WHEN to_char(next_day(CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,'sunday'),'iw')-6 <= to_char(next_day(m.COMPLETED_DT,'sunday'),'iw') THEN 'Yes'
ELSE 'No' END AS "Completed.Prior 6 Weeks"
```

The trouble is that this statement does not take into account the year, so now it is 2015, the business week is 1 and everything in the previous year has a greater business week.

I some how need to take into account the year as well, something like the below kind of works, but doesn't take into consideration the Business Week.

```
CURRENT_TIMESTAMP -42 >= m.COMPLETED_DT
```

Any help greatly appreciated

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Rather than using `TO_CHAR()` to get the business week (which I think means the week starting on Monday), you should use `TRUNC()` - this way the year is preserved:

```
, CASE WHEN TRUNC(NEXT_DAY(SYSDATE, 'sunday'), 'iw') - 42 >= 
            TRUNC(NEXT_DAY(m.COMPLETED_DT, 'sunday'), 'iw') THEN 'Yes'
  ELSE 'No' END AS "Completed.Prior 6 Weeks"
```

Note that I used `42` instead of `6` as Oracle date arithmetic uses days.

I'm not sure I see an advantage to using `CURRENT_TIMESTAMP` over `SYSDATE`. If you want to use the ANSI standard, you would want `CURRENT_DATE` ... I don't think you need the granularity of `CURRENT_TIMESTAMP` here, especially since you're truncating it. Also, you had `<=` when I think you mean `>=` (from what you have later in the question).